# Adding/ Editing list of people with photos

Tags: users, nodes

I've created a content type called 'Cast'. Authorized users need to have ability to create a different list of cast members, add/edit their info, upload photo. Essentially, it's a team roster problem.

I'm having hard time figuring out how to solve this problem? What module is most suitable for this purpose?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using Drupal Core itself with out using any module. Just follow below steps to solve the problem.

- Login as Super Admin
- Go to admin/people/permissions/roles
- Add a new role called "Cast Manager"
- Give Edit any and Create new "Cast"  Content Type permission to "Cast Manager" role in admin/people/permissions/roles

That's it ! Now, users who have "Cast Manager" role can edit any cast content and manage them !